# Alert Box Running First?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery/JS below. The first thing to run is the alert box at the end.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id1 img , .msg").stop().animate(
        { width: '300px', height: '300px'}, 
        { duration: 'slow', easing: 'easeInSine' }).pause(3000);

    $(".msg").animate(
        { width: '50px', height: '50px' }, 
        { duration: 498, easing: 'easeOutSine' });
    $("#id1 img").animate(
        { width: '50px', height: '50px' }, 
        { duration: 500, easing: 'easeOutSine' });

    $("#id1 img , .msg").animate(
        { width: '300px',height: '300px'}, 
        { duration: 'slow', easing: 'easeInSine' }).pause(3000);

    alert('eh?');
});
```

*I do have a [easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) plugin.*

If I run this the alert will show, and then the first animate will happen in the background but not be shown. It will just appear at the final size.

Shouldn't the alert run at the end of all the animation?

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pause plugin says that it "holds everything in the queue" for the specified amount of time. It will not actually pause execution (there is no sleep in javascript).

So, this is exactly the expected thing, that the alert will show up first.

Answer (score 5):

As other commenters have mentioned, the animate method is non-blocking and thus this is the correct behavior.  If you want the alert to be called at the end of an animation, take a look at the animate method's callback parameter.  The documentation states: "A function to be executed whenever the animation completes, executes once for each element animated against."

http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate

Answer (score 2):

jQuery animate does not block execution when animating. Instead, it is only queued when you call the statement $().animate is called.

Thus your alert() statement was "called first". But in fact, the animate statements was called before alert(), only that alert() has blocked execution before the animation is complete.

Answer (score 2):

Just as in the beginning of the code where you have the

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

That *function* states that after the document is ready, load the function that follows.
So at the end of the animation that you have running, you'll want to add another function telling it to run the alert *after* the animation completes.
Here's an example:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
     $("p").animate({width:25},3000,function(){
      alert("The paragraph has been animated");
    });
   });
  });
```

When the *button* is clicked, all *p* elements have their width shrunken to 25pixels over a period of 3seconds (jQuery reads in millisecons) and once that completes, it runs the *function*  of the *alert* "The paragraph has been animated".
Hope this helps.